# reshape dataframe based on event occurance and clearing

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, io, reshape

i want to see if there is an efficient way to reshape dataframe that is read from a tab separated csv file. the data consist of event codes and messages that are stacked up vertically with their timestamps. the data include a state column that specify whether an event occured (**TRUE**) or cleared (**FALSE**). i tried iterating through each row and update accordingly, but it is taking forever to complete.

every event code can occur and clear multiple times. every occur event (**TRUE**) is followed by clear event (**FALSE**) for every EventCode.

below example shows the format of the input file:

```
Timestamp                   State   Data    EventCode   EventMsg            Class
19-May-2023 16:10:09.301    FALSE   1       EventCode 1 EventCode 1 Message class 1
19-May-2023 16:10:09.300    FALSE   2       EventCode 2 EventCode 2 Message class 1
19-May-2023 16:10:09.299    TRUE    3       EventCode 1 EventCode 1 Message class 2
19-May-2023 16:10:09.298    FALSE   4       EventCode 4 EventCode 4 Message class 2
19-May-2023 16:10:09.297    FALSE   5       EventCode 3 EventCode 3 Message class 2
19-May-2023 16:10:09.296    TRUE    6       EventCode 2 EventCode 2 Message class 1
19-May-2023 16:10:09.295    TRUE    7       EventCode 4 EventCode 4 Message class 2
19-May-2023 16:10:09.294    TRUE    8       EventCode 3 EventCode 3 Message class 2
19-May-2023 16:10:09.293    FALSE   0       EventCode 1 EventCode 1 Message class 2
19-May-2023 16:10:09.292    TRUE    9       EventCode 1 EventCode 1 Message class 2
```

below shows desired final format:

```
OccurTimestamp              clearTimestamp          Data    EventCode   EventMsg            Class
19-05-2023 16:10:09.299     19-05-2023 16:10:09.301 3       EventCode 1 EventCode 1 Message class 1
19-05-2023 16:10:09.296     19-05-2023 16:10:09.300 6       EventCode 2 EventCode 2 Message class 1
19-05-2023 16:10:09.295     19-05-2023 16:10:09.298 7       EventCode 4 EventCode 3 Message class 2
19-05-2023 16:10:09.294     19-05-2023 16:10:09.297 8       EventCode 3 EventCode 4 Message class 2
19-05-2023 16:10:09.292     19-05-2023 16:10:09.293 9       EventCode 1 EventCode 1 Message class 1
```

Comment: Please clarify what each row in your desired output should describe in case an EventCode occurs several times. What happens when two events with EventCode 1 occur before one clears? Your example does not describe these cases.

Comment: done, refer to obove.  "every event code can occur and clear multiple times. every occur event (TRUE) is followed by clear event (FALSE) for every EventCode"

Comment: I edited my answer based on your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, I assume that each EventCode only exists exactly two times (once with `State = True` and once with `state = False`). Then this should work:

```py
# sort so that values with state = True are first
# then group the values based on EventCode
# then only get the first rows for each group (those with state = True)
# then reset the index to get a normal dataframe back
# and rename the Timestamp column to OccurTimestamp
new_df = df.sort_values(by = 'State', ascending=False) \
           .groupby('EventCode', group_keys=False) \
           .first() \
           .reset_index() \
           .rename(columns={'Timestamp': 'OccurTimestamp'})

# now we just need the corresponding clearTimetamps:
clear_timestamps = df[df['State'] == False][['Timestamp', 'EventCode']].rename(columns = {'Timestamp': 'clearTimestamp'})

# and merge both dataframes based on the EventCode
final = pd.merge(new_df, clear_timestamps, on = 'EventCode')
```

***Edit:*** Based on your additional info, I think you still need to iterate through the events as your problem inherently requires to check following events for a clear event.

You can still use

```py
grouped = df.groupby('EventCode')
```

as each group then only consists of the individual EventCodes preserving the order of your original dataframe. This avoids iterating over all other events when trying to find a corresponding clear event.

You can then iterate over each group via

```
for name, group in grouped:
    ...
```

Comment: did not work, it is not picking up the 2nd occurance (from top) of eventCode 1. instead it is relisting eventCode 1, 1st from top.

Comment: This is diffcult to analyze without seeing the code you used.

Comment: i just ran your code on the provided example.

Comment: The upper code is not updated for the new data format. Please read my post.